# Install a software once the download is complete

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to install a software once the download in complete. In my code I am trying to check whether the software is present in the download location or not. If it is present installation should start else wait. But I am not not able to achieve the expected result. Please help.

```
Set oReadObj  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oRead = oReadObj.OpenTextFile("C:\STMSetup\downloadlocation.txt", 1)

Dim intLineCounter

intLineCounter = 0

Do Until oRead.AtEndOfStream

    strLine = oRead.ReadLine
Loop

Set FSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strLine = filename
Do Until FSO.FileExists(filename) 
wscript.sleep 5000    
Loop
```

Comment: What, if any, errors are you receiving? What is the behavior you're experiencing in detail?

Comment: Not sure why you need Environment variables when you want to install a software. You will also need to provide if the software have Options to install silently/with config file/or any other switches. You also haven't got any `Exit Do` situation - are you trying to keep installing the software over and over until system hangs or rebooted?

Comment: I just want to install the software once, when file exists in the specified location. If not found wait for the file to be available. Please correct me where I am going wrong

Comment: I have updated my revised code. Still it's not working. please help